# Angular 7 form not showing "Go" button on ios keyboards

Tags: angular, accessibility

Got a dynamic form that has a structure of

```html
<form [formGroup'="form" (submit)="mySubmit()">
 <input type="text" formControlName="name" />
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The go button on the keyboard of an iphone or iphone is missing. All I see is return.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to have an action on the form.

```html
<!-- The # acts as a noop -->
<form action="#">
```

Otherwise iOS will not show the go button.